# Account # in SQL Tables

Tags: sql, join

I want to find if an account number is in 2 different tables (SQL 2005). If it is in table A I want to pull a value from it and if it is in table B I want to do the same. The account number should be in either table but not both.
Ex. If in Table A, select the account name else if in table B select the account date

This is what I have tried so far:

```
SELECT  a.AccountNumber
, CASE WHEN d.AccountNumber IS NULL THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS Status
```

FROM tableA a
    LEFT JOIN 
     (
    SELECT *
    FROM tableB b

```
UNION

SELECT *
FROM tableC c
WHERE AccountNumber NOT IN 
(
    SELECT AccountNumber FROM c
)
```

) d
ON a.Account = b.AccountNumber

Comment: Account Number = '234589'

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Any specific samples of data? You should have tried it yourself first and post your solutions (with warts and all) here before asking. Because even if your solution is incorrect that would generate interest and eventual correct solutions to your problem from the SO community at large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But if it is always true that account number may exist in one of the two tables and you are selecting similar columns, you can do something like below as well

```
SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3
FROM TABLEA
WHERE AccountNo=@AccNo
UNION
SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3
FROM TABLEB
WHERE AccountNo=@AccNo
```

Or you can try the long approarch

```
DECLARE @Contains BIT=0,
        @AccNo INT=234589

SELECT @Contains =1
FROM TABLEA
WHERE AccountNo=@AccNo

IF(@Contains=1)
BEGIN

   SELECT *
   FROM TABLEA
   WHERE AccountNo=@AccNo
END

ELSE 
BEGIN
   SELECT *
   FROM TABLEB
   WHERE AccountNo=@AccNo
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the `JOIN` in the right place:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN a.AccountNumber IS NULL 
THEN 'Not in Table A' 
WHEN b.AccountNumber IS NULL Then ' Not in Table B' 
END AS 'Status' 
FROM TableA a 
INNER JOIN TableB b 
ON b.AccID = a.AccID
WHERE AccountNumber = '234598'
```